# What is the name of this creature?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, molluscs

[image]

What is the name of this creature?

It looks like either a crustacean or a conch.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[**Nautilus.**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nautilus)

[image: flat helical shell with tentacles and eyes - and a fair bit of plate-armour2]

<sup>**Nautilus belauensis.** Licenced under [CC ASA 3.0 unported](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/deed.en), via Wikipedia 2022 from user Manuae.</sup>

Mollusca -> Cephalopoda (like squid and octopus) -> Nautilaceae ->  Nautilidae - comprising of six extant species.

They range the 200m to 700m depth of the Indo-Pacific, scavenging carrion.

They seem to have been more-or less the same over the last 500 million years according to the fossil record - then being up to 2.5 metres in shell diameter, being more modest now at a maximum of 22 cm (10 inches) when fully grown.

They move via jet-propulsion by drawing water in through their hyphonome, then expelling it with force, as seen in the "front view" here:

[image: spout showing in mid squirt]

<sup>From Profberger at English Wikipedia, freely licensed.</sup>